# jQuery checking which radiobutton is checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I got 2 radiobutton and 1 radcombobox

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="cbxYes" Width="60" Height="30" runat="server" GroupName="proffesional" OnCheckedChanged="cbxYes_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="cbxNo" runat="server" Width="60" Height="30" GroupName="proffesional" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbxNo_CheckedChanged" />
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="dblSelect" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="#d8d8d8" runat="server" Width="200" Height="30" ></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

. don't use `clientidmode=static` and i want to show or hide radcombobox according what radiobutton is checked.

I have written this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function () {
    var dropdown = $('#<%= dblSelect.ClientID%>');
    var radio1 = $('#<%= cbxYes.ClientID%>');
    var radio2 = $('#<%= cbxNo.ClientID%>');
    if ((radio1.is(':checked').val()) == 'true') {
        dropdown.is(':visible').val() = 'true';
    };
    if((radio2.is(':checked').val() == 'false'){
        dropdown.is(':visible').val() = 'false';
    };
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the problem?  What is the code doing and what do you want it to do?  Please spell out what you want to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery's `is` returns a boolean.

```
if (radio1.is(':checked')) {
    dropdown.show();
};
if(radio2.is(':checked')){
    dropdown.hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Asp.Net 4
and use `clientidmode="static"`

```
$(document).ready({

    if ($("#cbxYes[type='radio']:checked").val() == 'true') {
        $("#dblSelect").fadeIn();
    };
    if ($("#cbxNo[type='radio']:checked").val() == 'true') {
        $("#dblSelect").fadeOut();
    };
});
```

You can even make it shorter:

```
$(document).ready({
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function () { 
        $("#dblSelect").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: i don't use clientidmode="static"

Comment: that does make your jquery cleaner http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx

Comment: i using asp controls and telerik there is no chance (as far as i know) to change clientidmode

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function () {
    var dropdown = $('#<%= dblSelect.ClientID%>');
    var radio1 = $('#<%= cbxYes.ClientID%>');
    var radio2 = $('#<%= cbxNo.ClientID%>');
    if (radio1.is(':checked') == true) {
        dropdown.show();
    };
    if(radio2.is(':checked') == false){
        dropdown.hide();
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: there was a bug in the code (too many brackets) - can you try it now.